# How to write Ordered List and show number of input entries stored in array

Tags: javascript

When users SHOW button the data is displayed I need help with
1.clear the input fields when show is clicked for the next input
2.Show data in ordered list like 1,2,3
3.Show how many times the data was stored

```
 <form>
    First Name<input id = "name1" /> 
    Last Name <input id ="name2"/> 
    City <input id ="city"/>
    </form>
    <button onclick="getResult()">SHOW</button>
    <br><br>
    <br>
    <h3>Student Data </h3>
    <output id="out"/>
    <br>
    <script>
    var arr=[];
    function getResult(){
    var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
    var name2 =document.getElementById('name2').value;
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    var students={
    firstName:name1,lastName:name2,cityName:city
    }
    arr.push(students);
    var k='';
    for(var g=0;g<arr.length;g++)
    k=k+"<ol><li>"+arr[g].firstName+" "+arr[g].lastName+" "+arr[g].cityName+"       </li></ol>";
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = k;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing:**

1. After added list input was cleared.(empty the input data)
2. order list like 1,2,3 .I was removed the default list order. Manually apply with increment value.`eval(g+1)`
3. In console.log its shows how many times your stored the data in array `arr.length`

```js
var arr=[];
    function getResult(){
    var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
    var name2 =document.getElementById('name2').value;
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    var students={
    firstName:name1,lastName:name2,cityName:city
    }
    arr.push(students);
    var k='';
    for(var g=0;g<arr.length;g++)
    k=k+" <li>"+eval(g+1)+'.'+arr[g].firstName+" "+arr[g].lastName+" "+arr[g].cityName+"       </li>";
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = k;
    document.getElementById('name1').value="";
    document.getElementById('name2').value="";
document.getElementById('city').value="";
 document.getElementById('store').innerHTML='store in= ' +arr.length +'times';
}
```

```css
li{
  list-style:none;
  }
```

```html
<form >
    First Name<input id = "name1" required/> 
    Last Name <input id ="name2"  required/> 
    City <input id ="city"  required/>
    </form>

      <button onclick="getResult()" >SHOW</button>
    <br><br>
<p id="store"></p>
    <br>
    <h3>Student Data </h3>
    <output id="out"/>
    <br>
```

Comment: How can I show number of stored values like , normal data values

Comment: use `arr.length`  it show the number of stored values .see the updated answer

Comment: Thank your ver much sir prasad.

Comment: Welcome @UmarSatti  & dont forget to mark as a answer .

Answer (score 0):

Call `name1.value = name2.value = city.value = "";` following `for` loop. The list items will display how many elements are in `arr` array and how many times button has been clicked.

```html
<form>
  First Name
  <input id="name1" />Last Name
  <input id="name2" />City
  <input id="city" />
</form>
<button onclick="getResult()">SHOW</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Student Data </h3>
<output id="out" />
<br>
<script>
  var arr = [];

  function getResult() {
    var name1 = document.getElementById('name1');
    var name2 = document.getElementById('name2');
    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    
    var students = {
      firstName: name1.value,
      lastName: name2.value,
      cityName: city.value
    }
    arr.push(students);
    var k = '';
    for (var g = 0; g < arr.length; g++) {
      k = k + "<ol><li>" 
          + arr[g].firstName + " " 
          + arr[g].lastName + " " 
          + arr[g].cityName 
          + "</li></ol>";
    };
    name1.value = name2.value = city.value = "";
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = k;
  }
</script>
```